Is there a concept of sexual transmutation in Torah?
Hi in some of the certain secular books I have seen before taking Torah more seriously for example in Think and Grow Rich it says that a person can transmute (transform) the energy of his Zera to different energy like in other areas of life and that would bring more happiness to him.
Is there a similar concept in Torah and Kabbalah that could help console a person more with this situation especially when he is alone at the momemnt without a partner for example like instead of committing Zera Levatalah he can just transform the Zera into another form of energy?
And if possible according to the Torah can the Zera actully change into a different form of energy?

Does this mean, without any emission? Or is this question trying to find some "kosher" way to spill seed?

If it's the former, it sounds like there is excessive sexual energy due to lack of sexual contact. The Torah approach is that, this doesn't need to be. If one guards one's eyes, and one's brit properly, as well as works on one's spiritual stature by learning Torah etc. one will not be plagued by excessive sexual energy. The Kabbalah discusses many (thousands) of levels of mastery of this. Don't buy the modern line that everyone is doomed by their nature to have sexual energy that can only be got rid of by spending it...
